# Finding an isometry between two subspaces of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

So, I'm given a Hilbert space which is the direct sum $H=H_1\oplus H_2$ of two separable Hilbert spaces $H_j$. There is a closed subspace $D\subseteq H$ which satisfies that it is not a subspace of *either* $H_j$ (i.e., it is *only* a subspace of their direct sum). Define orthogonal projections $P_j$ which map onto $H_j$, respectively. My aim is to construct a surjective, linear isometry $J:P_1D\rightarrow P_2D$ (here, $J$ is *isometric* if $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle Ju,Jv\rangle$ for any $u,v\in D(J)$), so that $D=\{u+Ju~|~u\in D(J):=P_1D\}$. I am almost totally stumped by this.

It should also be noted that due to the larger context of the question the following can be taken as given: for $u,v\in D$, we have $\langle P_1u,P_1v\rangle=\langle P_2u,P_2v\rangle$.

My first approach was to try to define an inverse of $P_1$ on $D(J)$, but this won't work unless $P_1$ is injective into $D(J)$ (which is certainly not guaranteed), so I gave up on that.

My second attempt involved separating $D$ using separability of $H$; but by the same general lack of injectivity of $P_j$, one cannot guarantee that, for a complete orthonormal sequence $(v_k)_{k=1}^N$ for $D$ (with $N\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$), $(P_jv_k)_{k=1}^N$ is also a complete orthonormal sequence for $P_jD$; furthermore throwing away any vectors $P_jv_k$ which destroy orthonormality of the sequence removes the possibility of defining the map $J$ by using this method.

Can anybody offer any pointers/hints on how to achieve my goal? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In your third sentence, what is $D_j$?  Is it supposed to be $H_j$?

Comment: Yes,  sorry! Edited.

Answer (score 2):

The existence of $J$ would imply that $P_1D$ and $P_2D$ are isometric. This is not the case in general: let $H_1=\mathbb C^2$, $H_2=\mathbb C^3$, and 
$$
D=\{(0,a)\oplus(b,c,0):\ a,b,c\in\mathbb C\}.
$$
Then $P_1D$ is one-dimensional, while $P_2D$ is two-dimensional.

Comment: I can see what you mean. I have to point out that in this case the existence of such an isometry $J$ doesn't guarantee that that its domain and image are isometrically *isomorphic*, merely that $J$ preserves the inner product (and hence the norm). Now, if in the general case, we are given the following two further properties, would construction of such a $J$ be possible? (i) for any $u\in D$ we have $\|P_1u\|=\|P_2u\|$, and (ii) $\dim(P_1D)\geq\dim(P_2D)$.

Comment: Your condition (i) implies that $P_1=P_2$, which is impossible in your setup.

Comment: That is not obvious to me. What is your reasoning? I'm simply saying that both projections of some vector in $D$ have the same *size*, in the Hilbert space norm. (Indeed this is a fact I have derived from the larger context in which lies my question; it would be quite concerning to me if (i) could *not* hold!)

Comment: Apologies, the result I stated above holds in an even more general form. I've updated the official question.

Answer (score 1):

If such a $J$ exists, we must necessarily have $D \cap H_2 = \{0\}$. For $P_1(u+Ju) = P_1(u) = u$, so $d = P_1(d) + J(P_1(d))$ for all $d \in D$. $D\cap H_2 = \{0\}$ means the projection $P_1$ is injective on $D$, and $J = P_2 \circ (P_1\lvert_D)^{-1}$.

Conversely, if $D\cap H_2 = \{0\}$, $(P_1\lvert_D)^{-1}$ exists and $J = P_2 \circ (P_1\lvert_D)^{-1}$ is a linear isometry $J \colon P_1(D) \to P_2(D)$ - due to the premise $\langle P_1u, P_1v\rangle = \langle P_2 u, P_2 v\rangle$ for all $u,v\in D$. Since $(P_1\lvert_D)^{-1} \colon P_1(D) \to D$ is surjective, also $J \colon P_1(D) \to P_2(D)$ is surjective.

Summarising: A $J\colon P_1(D) \to P_2(D)$ with the desired properties exists if and only if $P_1\lvert_D$ is injective (which means, if and only if $D\cap H_2 = \{0\}$). The premise

$$\langle P_1u, P_1v\rangle = \langle P_2 u, P_2 v\rangle\tag{1}$$ for all $u,v\in D$ guarantees that $D\cap H_2 = \{0\}$, for if $v \in D \cap H_2$, then we have

$$0 =\lVert P_1 v\rVert^2 = \lVert P_2 v\rVert^2 = \lVert v\rVert^2$$

by $(1)$.